# How to add buttons to the bottom of a Xamarin screen with a tabbed control?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I deliberately described it in natural language.

I'm using Visal Studio 2022, Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2244.

I want to create a screen in Xamarin (in a Shell app) with a tabbed view filling up most of the page, but with buttons or a navigation bar at the bottom.

I can create a TabbedPage like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Waiter.Xmrn.ViewModels.TableParties"
        x:Class="..."
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        BindingContext="{Binding ...}" >
</TabbedPage>
```

and add tab pages as ContentPage's

But this results in a tab control taking up the whole screen, without any room for the extra bottom-bound controls, and the shell navigation TabBar is not visible either. If I add the bottom controls to the tab pages, they will be part of the tab pages and slide with them (repeated on all tab page) which looks rather silly.

I found this Xamarin.Forms change request (for Android only): https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1675
If I follow this, the tab page headers are displayed at the bottom of the screen and the shell navigation TabBar is also displayed- with the tab page headers and TabBar buttons overlayed on each other.

Do I need to get rid of Shell? Or TabbedPage? Or both?

Comment: TabbedPage is intended to fill the entire screen and be the root navigation control.  If you want tabs inside of another element, you can try TabView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Comment: As Jason mentioned, use TabView with [examples here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/501), or [Sharpnado.Tabs](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.tabs)

Comment: Thank you Jason, Shaw, will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview) to achieve this function.
[image]

For example,to achieve the following function as follows,we can use the following code:

```
    <xct:TabView
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            TabStripBackgroundColor="Blue"
            TabStripHeight="60"
            TabIndicatorColor="Yellow"
            TabContentBackgroundColor="Yellow">

            <!-- First TabViewItem -->

            <xct:TabViewItem
                Text="Tab 2"   
                Icon="circle.png"
                ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FabTabItemTemplate}"
                Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"
                TabTapped="OnFabTabTapped" />

            <!-- Third TabViewItem -->
    </xct:TabView>
```

For more ,you can check article [Beautiful Tabs with Xamarin Community Toolkit TabView](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-community-toolkit-tabview/) .

Besides, you can also use Shell to achieve this.

For more about this, you can check thread [Xamarin Bottom Custom Tab Bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/170862/xamarin-bottom-custom-tab-bar.html?childToView=222394#answer-222394).

Bhuwancb99 has posted the sample code in the last comment.

Comment: Hi @balintn, how about the issue, is there anything to update?